# Apply a User-defined Force on a Solid Node in Webots

Tags: webots, node-supervisor

I have been trying to add a 5KN force on the solid node named 'LLarm' on a robot in Webots from a matlab code using this function:

```
void wb_supervisor_node_add_force('LLarm', 5000, true)
```

but i get this error:
Undefined function 'void' for input arguments of type 'char'.
Error in atlas_matlab (line 12)
void wb_supervisor_node_add_force('LLarm', 5000, true)
Error in launcher (line 161)
eval(WEBOTS_CONTROLLER_NAME);

Comment: The second argument should be an array. The force is described as a 3-dimensional vector, along the X, Y, and Z axes.

Comment: Thank you, noted.
But i am facing problems with the first argument. any idea about how i can introduce a solid node (the 1st input argument) to this function?

Comment: You have to get a reference to the Solid node. For example, you can achieve it using the `wb_supervisor_node_get_from_def` function:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor#wb_supervisor_node_get_from_def

Answer (score 0):

The force is described as a 3-dimensional vector, along the X, Y, and Z axes, see here:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab-language=matlab#wb_supervisor_node_add_force

You have to get a reference to the Solid node, see here:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/supervisor?tab-language=matlab#wb_supervisor_node_get_from_def

Finally, your code should look something like this:

```matlab
node_ref = wb_supervisor_node_get_from_def('LLARM_DEF'); % Set DEF for your solid
wb_supervisor_node_add_force(node_ref, [x, y, z], true);
```